# Pydantic: How to Pass str and list to the same variable

Tags: python, pydantic

I have a program that inserts responses to a MongoDB collection. Some of the questions require multiple responses. Questions with multiple responses use checkboxes and those that require a single response use a radio button.

The values of the checkboxes are stored in an array, whereas the values of the radio button are stored as strings. My problem is that if the user selects one checkbox, it inserts it into the DB but multiple responses through an error. How can I make my code to accept both list and str based on what is selected?

Here are my sample codes

**index.ts**

`questionAnswers: string | strong[]`

**submit.py**

`questionAnswers: Optional[str]`

How can I implement the same logic found in the index.ts to submit.py?

Thank you

**Edited**
Let's assume that I have two questions with various options. For example:

**Question 1**
questions: 'how did you hear about us?'
options: ['friends', 'radio', 'tv']
The option above is a checkbox

**Question 2**
questions: 'can you help me?'
options: 'yes' 'no'
This uses a radio button

Each option has a point. I want to sum the scores for all chosen options. So, if the user chooses [friends, radio], and yes, I want to check if what is selected is in the options with the code below:

```
for index, question in enumerate(questions):
   questionScore = question['options'].index(question['questionAnswers'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python typing equivalent of `string | string[]` is `Union[str, List[str]]`.  As of Python 3.10 (see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0604/) you can also do `str | List[str]`.

If you're hitting a runtime error, you'll need to check the type at runtime, e.g.:

```
def handle(question_answers: Union[str, List[str]]):
    if isinstance(question_answers, list):
        # do thing with list
    elif isinstance(question_answers, str):
        # do thing with str
    else:
        raise TypeError("somebody forgot to run mypy")
```

Comment: When I used questionAnswers: Union[str, list[str]], I get ValueError:... Is not in list

Comment: Sounds like a different problem.  I don't think you hit that exception executing that particular line of code, but in some other part of `submit.py` that you haven't shared.  Obviously I can't debug code you haven't shared.  Good luck!  :)

Comment: Sorry! Here is the line of code that is throwing the error: questionScore = question['options'].index(question['questionAnswers'])

Comment: I assume that's happening because the thing you're looking for isn't in the list you're looking for it in.  Again, I can't debug that because I don't know what `question` contains.

Comment: I have update my question. Sorry for the trouble

Comment: Knowing that `question` is an element of `questions` doesn't help me at all if I don't have a value for `questions`.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Questions with their corresponding options are stored and retrieved from DB. I listed two of them in my edited portion of this post. I am new to Python programming. How do I check why the selected options are not on the list. A sample question is: **What are some of your favorite coping strategies? Check all that apply.** The options are ['Grounding technique', 'Journaling', 'Expressing yourself through art or a hobby', 'Other']. However, if you select two from these options, i get this error: ***<class 'ValueError'>: ['Journaling', 'Other'] is not in list**

Comment: Have your code print out `questions` so you can see what its actual content in Python is.  Knowing that it's a radio button or a checkbox in the browser is meaningless if I don't know how it's represented as a Python object.  The idea of a minimal reproducible example is that you should be able to come up with some Python code that can be run *on its own* and demonstrate the same problem that you're trying to solve.

Comment: Thank you. I have been able to solve it. I did: ```if isinstance(question_answers, list): if question["questionAnswers"] in question["options"]: questionScore = question['options'].index(question['questionAnswers'])```